# VB.NET Private Function Implement C#

Tags: c#, vb.net

In VB.NET, you can make a private function that implements an interface as follows, so that it does not clutter up your class:

```
Public Class Class0
    Implements Interface0
    Private Sub MySuperSecretFunction Implements Interface0.Func0
        'Do something really cool
    End Sub
End Class
```

What is the C# equivalent of this? I compared Microsoft's documentation for the two languages, and I couldn't find it. In the examples provided, the C# functions did not appear to explicitly define which interface functions they were overriding.

Any explanation would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Have  a look [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/interfaces/explicit-interface-implementation).

Comment: It is not explicit in C#, it looks for a simple method name match.  Sometimes that can create ambiguity, then you make it explicit by also naming the interface in the method name.  You can still declare them *private* to avoid clutter, you should.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [*explicit interface implementation*](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/interfaces/explicit-interface-implementation), which is implicitly private:

```cs
public class Class0 : Interface0
{
    void Interface0.Func0()
    {
        // Implementation
    }
}
```

Comment: Shouldn't `implements` be a `:`?

Comment: Some things you cannot do in C#, annoyingly: implement an interface using a private  *or public* function named something else, or implement multiple interface functions with the same function. There are workarounds but they're annoying.